# App uninstallation event in flurry

Tags: java, android, uninstallation, flurry

Is it possible to log this type of events without implementing some custom functionality? What I already know, android does not provide possibility to detect this type of events by application itself.

App deinstallation, are probably one of the events you definitely want to have in flurry, so I assume it should be doable, just can not find clear way how. Any ideas?